# Android app-action with custom query pattern

Tags: android, actions-on-google, app-actions

I have an android app that using **com.google.android.gms.actions.SEARCH_ACTION**
to search a phrase on my app using **search for PHRASE on APP_NAME**, but now I want use custom voice command like **APP_NAME PHRASE** to open my app and pass that phrase using google assistant.
So is it possible to implement this feature?

I have tried with https://github.com/actions-on-google/appactions-fitness-kotlin to get deep idea about actually how action intent works and found that it may be possible using deep linking.

Here in this example  in ***actions.xml*** file one action **actions.intent.GET_EXERCISE_OBSERVATION** implemented as you can see below code.

```
<action intentName="actions.intent.GET_EXERCISE_OBSERVATION">

        <fulfillment
            fulfillmentMode="actions.fulfillment.SLICE"
            urlTemplate="content://com.devrel.android.fitactions.FitSliceProvider/stats{?exerciseType}">

            <parameter-mapping
                entityMatchRequired="true"
                intentParameter="exerciseObservation.aboutExercise.name"
                required="true"
                urlParameter="exerciseType" />

        </fulfillment>

        <fulfillment
            fulfillmentMode="actions.fulfillment.DEEPLINK"
            urlTemplate="https://fit-actions.firebaseapp.com/stats" />


        <parameter name="exerciseObservation.aboutExercise.name">
            <entity-set-reference entitySetId="ExerciseEntitySet" />
        </parameter>

</action>

<!-- Defines an entity set with our supported entities -->

<entity-set entitySetId="ExerciseEntitySet">

        <entity
            name="@string/activity_running"
            alternateName="@array/runningSynonyms"
            identifier="RUNNING" />
        <entity
            name="@string/activity_walking"
            alternateName="@array/walkingSynonyms"
            identifier="WALKING" />
        <entity
            name="@string/activity_cycling"
            alternateName="@array/cyclingSynonyms"
            identifier="CYCLING" />
</entity-set>
```

But now I have some questions regarding this code.

1. How urlTemplate **`content://com.devrel.android.fitactions.FitSliceProvider/stats{?exerciseType}`** for ***actions.fulfillment.SLICE*** is generated?
2. Can **exerciseObservation.aboutExercise.name** have any custom value rather then defined in **entity-set** ?
3. How urlTemplate **`https://fit-actions.firebaseapp.com/stats`** for ***actions.fulfillment.DEEPLINK*** is generated?

After implementing this I think **`actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE`** will be helpful with the help of DEEPLINK fulfillment.

So is it possible to implement this using **actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE"**?

Answer (score 2):

> 1. How urlTemplate **`content://com.devrel.android.fitactions.FitSliceProvider/stats{?exerciseType}`**
>      for ***actions.fulfillment.SLICE*** is generated?

The `urlTemplate` value (whether fulfilling via slice or deep link) is fully up to you to define. In the case of a deep link, this is the URL the system will call to open up your app. In the case of a Slice, this is the contentUri the system will call to render the Slice. The parameters inside the {} will be expanded with values at runtime. To get a better understanding of how that works, see the docs [here](https://developers.google.com/actions/appactions/reference/actionsxml#fulfillment_with_url_templates) and [here](https://developers.google.com/actions/appactions/reference/actionsxml#fulfillment) or the [Google I/O 2019 session](https://youtu.be/vQALSeGy9aY?t=603).

> 2. Can **exerciseObservation.aboutExercise.name** have any custom value rather then defined in **entity-set** ?

I'm not exactly sure what you mean here but let me try and give more detail. The param **name** of `exerciseObservation.aboutExercise.name` is set for each Assistant Intent can cannot be changed. These values are listed in the documentation ([example](https://developers.google.com/actions/appactions/bii-integrations#answer_exercise_queries)). The actual values of the parameters (that are populated by the user's query at runtime) are dynamic and will change based on the user's query and the Assistant Intent. For each Assistant Intent, you can refer to the docs to see what the possible values can be. In some cases they are from a set list of values (like for [`GET_EXERCISE_OBSERVATION`](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/built-in-intents/app-actions#get-exercise-observation)), for others it could be a free form value based on the user's input, and for others still you can optionally extend the values using [inline inventory](https://developers.google.com/actions/appactions/quickstart#inline-inventory) (this is what you use `<entity-set>` for in your example).

> 3. How urlTemplate **`https://fit-actions.firebaseapp.com/stats`** for
>      ***actions.fulfillment.DEEPLINK*** is generated?

As per #1, the value of `urlTemplate` is totally up to you to configure. It can be any Android Intent URI. The system will call this Uri to start up your app/Activity.

> After implementing this I think
>   **`actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE`** will be helpful with the
>   help of DEEPLINK fulfillment.
>
> So is it possible to implement this using
>   **actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE"**?

`OPEN_APP_FEATURE` is just another Assistant Intent that allows a generic call into a feature of your app. The [docs](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/built-in-intents/app-actions#open-app-feature) were recently updated with some example queries. Eg.

> Open ***Youtube*** *history*

This example will open the app named "YouTube" and pass the feature name "history" to the app to handle.

> Open ***Example App*** *Example feature*

This example will open the app named "Example App" and pass the feature name "Example feature" to the app to handle.

Comment: Could you please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64484644/google-assistant-not-taking-the-new-uri-on-android-app