# Google assistant not taking the new URI on Android app

Tags: android, actions-on-google, app-actions

I'm Integrating the google assistant using App Actions and BII(Built-in Intents).
The issue is when I tried with the voice command it's not opening the intended screen rather it just opens the app..when I debugged it incoming URI is different(Old one) but I have a different one now.

> **Actions.Xml**

```
<actions>
<action intentName="actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE">
    <!-- Each parameter can reference an entity set using a custom ID. -->
    <parameter name="feature">
        <entity-set-reference entitySetId="FeatureEntitySet" />
    </parameter>

    <fulfillment urlTemplate="myappname://speed test/open{?appFeature}">
        <parameter-mapping
            intentParameter="feature"
            urlParameter="appFeature" />
    </fulfillment>
</action>

<entity-set entitySetId="FeatureEntitySet">
    <entity
        name="speedtest"
        identifier="SPEED TEST" />
    <!--<entity
        name="second feature"
        identifier="FEATURETWO" />-->
</entity-set>
```

> **AndroidManifest**

```
<activity
        android:name=".activities.SupportActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "myappname://speed test” -->
            <data
                android:host="speed test"
                android:scheme="myappname" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

> **SupportActivity.java**

```
private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    String appLinkAction = intent.getAction();
    Uri appLinkData = intent.getData();

    if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(appLinkAction) && appLinkData != null) {
        String appFeature = appLinkData.getQueryParameter("appFeature");
        if (appFeature != null && appFeature.contains("SPEED TEST")) {
            //startActivity or do something
           
        }
    }
}
```

Google Assistant Voice Command:
"Open [my app name] speed test" then it just opens the app
"Open [myappname] support" then it opens the intended activity where the intent filter defined

Uri String - myappname://speed test/open?appFeature=support on giving voice command "Open [myappname] [support]"
but when I give voice command as Open [myappname] [speed test] it launches the app.
In-App Action Test Tool working but not with google assistant neither voice nor text.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using 3.4.2+ App Actions Test Tool (AATT). Showing the old URL is a sign that the preview hasn't been updated with the latest `actions.xml`.

Comment: I have the latest one 3.4.2 AATT, but google assistant voice command behaving weird even text.

Comment: tried custom intent it works fine, looks like an issue with BII "Open_app_feature"

Comment: @Girish do you have some open source example of how did you implemented those custom actions? I have been facing situation AATT invoke my custom action but google assistant does not understand (and open web search instead). It would be nice to see at least one working example on the web (I can't still find anything)